# How do I break a looping menu on Python

Tags: menu

I have a little problem on making ecounter for fast food, the problems is at continuing order.
I don't know how to use True and False in python..
I choose three food as a beginner. It's end up failing..
So I tried to use True by copying other people code.
at first the code was success, but when i changed a little thing in code, it went wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

so far this is my code:

```
hcount = 0
scount = 0
fcount = 0
y = True
n = False
cstm= input("Please enter your name: ")
print("                                       ")
print("                                       ")
print("Hi MR/MS " + cstm)
print("WELCOME TO MACDUNNO ECOUNTER")

print("CHOOSE YOUR FOOD")

while True:

    print("  ")
    print('MENU MAC DUNNO')
    print("1. HAMBURGER = $1.50")
    print("2. SODA      = $1.15")
    print("3. FRIES   = $1.25")

    choice = int(input('ENTER NUMBER 1-3: '))

    if choice == 1:
        amount = int(input("ENTER THE AMOUNT: "))
        hcount += amount
    elif choice == 2:
        amount = int(input("ENTER THE AMOUNT: "))
        scount += amount
    elif choice == 3:
        amount = int(input("ENTER THE AMOUNT: "))
        fcount += amount
        
        
    countinue = input("ARE YOU STILL WANT TO ORDER? (y/n)")
    if countinue == n:
        sub = (hcount * 1.50) + (scount * 1.15) + (fcount * 1.25)
        tax = sub * 0.09
        total = sub + tax
        print("                                           ")
        print("                                           ")
        print("************")
        print("PAYMENT")
        print("************")
        print('TOTAL HAMBURGER: {0}'.format(hcount))
        print('TOTAL SODA: {0}'.format(scount))
        print('TOTAL FRIES: {0}'.format(fcount))
        print(" ")
        print('SUBTOTAL: {:0.2f}'.format(sub))
        print('TAX : {:0.2f}'.format(tax))
        print("   ")
        print("__________________________________")
        print('TOTAL: {:0.2f}'.format(total))
        print("   ")
        pay =int(input("INSERT PAYMENT:"))

        if pay > total :
            exchange = pay - total
            print(' ')
            print(' ')
            print('EXCHANGE : {:0.2f}'.format(exchange))
            print("THANK YOU, PLEASE COME AGAIN")
            import time
            time.sleep(5)
                        
        else:
            print(' ')
            print(' ')
            print("INSUFFICIENT AMOUNT")
            print("PLEASE INSERT THE RIGHT AMOUNT")
            scpay = int(input("INSERT PAYMENT : "))
        if scpay > total :
            exchange = scpay - total
            print(' ')
            print(' ')
            print('EXCHANGE     : {:0.2f}'.format(exchange))
            print("THANK YOU, PLEASE COME AGAIN")
            import time
            time.sleep(5)
                        
        else:
            print("  ")
            print("ORDER TERMINATED")
            import time
            time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

place break after a statement after which you want to stop your loop 
for ex.

```
if choice == 1:
        amount = int(input("ENTER THE AMOUNT: "))
        hcount += amount
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a variable another variable True for when the ordering is taking place and then at each possible break or each possible option of ending the order you must make the variable False.

Example

```
     ordering = True
     while ordering:
         .
         .
         ordering = False
         print("THANK YOU, PLEASE COME AGAIN")
         import time
         time.sleep(5)
```